# Alternatives to generate the java code from the WSDL and xsd from the local files

Tags: java

We have a SOAP axis2 server that we cannot control that exposes some webservices.
We created a webservice client using the wsdl from that webservice. It generated the java code from the wsdl using Eclipse

This will be deployed in production but if the server adds a outputfield for example, our code will break and we will need to generate the java code again, make a jar and deploy on the server.

This does not make any sense. It should be 100% or extremely close of update.
Does it make sense to generate the java code from the WSDL and xsd from the local files?

All the examples I saw were like this

Comment: Making webservices from local wsdl and xsd files makes sens if they match the exposed ones by the `URL_TO_WEB_SERVICE?wsdl` url

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your JAXB2-Deserializer to ignore unkown (optional) elements, that preserves a bit of compatibility. Or modify the generated xsd to allow additional elements (xs:any) on the desired level.

But yes, that's a problem mostly solved by management

Comment: Do you know howt? I'm using Axis2 1.5.6 and I generated the java code from Eclipse WebService Client

Comment: sorry, no axis expert, perhaps there's a way to configure the underlying jaxb. Look for a ValidationEventHandler on the Unmarshaller